# Get IPAddress from a hostname

Tags: c#, asp.net, hostname

I want to get IP address of a host on my `aspx` page using `C#`, I'm using DNS class methods to get these.

It worked fine locally, but when I deployed the solution on IIS7 it returned only the IP address assigned by ISP but I want local IP address of that machine.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Local IP Address means the address a machine has on a lan like 192.168.xxx.xxx

Comment: So the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` suggested by Muhammad Akhtar is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Example for this.
In this example we can get IP address of our given host name.

```
    string strHostName = "www.microsoft.com";
    // Get DNS entry of specified host name
    IPAddress[] addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName).AddressList;

    // The DNS entry may contains more than one IP addresses.
    // Iterate them and display each along with the type of address (AddressFamily).
    foreach (IPAddress address in addresses)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("{0} = {1} ({2})", strHostName, address, address.AddressFamily));
        Response.Write("<br/><br/>");
    }
```

Comment: Please note that Moderators and other users are deleting your spammy links to your own website out of your answers. Please stop including them, to avoid harsher sanctions for these links.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident that you can not get the local 192.168.C.D address of the local machine like this.

This is because of security and visibility (NAT's etc).

If you are looking to uniquely identify a user. I would look to sessions or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

When looking up the ip address in a public DNS, you will get the officiall IP address communicated outwards. If NAT is used and you want the internal address you have to connect to a DNS server which holds the internal IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method...

```
public static String GetIP()
{
    String ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
    {
        ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    return ip;
}
```

Comment: This is the closest you can get to a solution but it is no guarantee that it will work. The intermediate routers can set what ever IP in the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR variable.

Comment: this is for the server machine ip, i want to get the ip of any machine on LAN.

Comment: This will return client IP, can you try.

Comment: Thanks for you help Akhtar, but the problem is, i have hostname of some machine and i have to evaluate the ip of that machine will this help in this case?

Comment: You can check but I am not sure.